# Plane flying with constant velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, aerodynamics

The main forces acting on a plane are the Lift , weight , drag and thrust forces.
Suppose the plane is moving with a constant velocity , then by applying Newton's 2nd law , the summation of forces is equal to zero since there's no acceleration. But this also means that the weight force should be canceled with it's opposing lift force , and the thrust force should be as well be canceled with it's opposing drag force. But wait... how could the plane then be moving with the constant velocity  if the thrust force was canceled , which is the force responsible for moving it forward ?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand, you are thinking something like this:

1. Everything needs a forward force to keep moving at a constant speed.
2. Things without a forward force start to slow down until they stop.
3. The forward force of thrust is cancelled by the backward force of drag, so the plane has no forward force, so it will slow down.

This is how most people think motion works. The problem is that Thought 1 and Thought 2 are simply not true. Newton's first law says that things move at constant velocities without changing their motion unless some outside force acts on them. Specifically, objects do not need forward forces to move forward at a constant speed! All the plane needs to keep moving at a constant speed is for no net external force to act on it, and we have accomplished that by making the thrust equal the drag.

To help yourself understand you might ask yourself a few questions. You have imagined that since there is no forward force the plane will slow down. Why will it slow down? Slowing down needs an explanation, so which is it? If your answer is "drag" then you must ask why the drag still works when it is cancelled by the thrust.

You correctly used Newton's second law when you noticed that the constant speed implies that the forces cancel. It looks like you haven't quite internalized Newton's laws all the way, but you're almost there. Here's how I would write the correct thought process.

1. Everything moves at a constant velocity unless an outside net force acts on it.
2. Things on earth that are moving experience the external force of drag.
3. Hence, objects on earth that move at a constant speed must exert another forward force to cancel the drag so that there is no net force.

Answer (score 1):

At some point before reaching maximum velocity, the thrust force and lift force are greater than the drag force and weight, this is how it gains it's non-zero velocity.

As you approach the constant velocity part of the travel, the lift force and thrust forces get closer and closer to the weight and drag force.  To maintain a constant velocity at cruising speed; the pilot just has to make sure that they only supply enough thrust and lift to cancel out the effects of weight and drag forces.

The same thing happens when you travel at a constant speed in a car.  You need to supply the right amount of power to the engine to compensate for the movement resistance of the car, and you can control this to reach many different constant velocities.

Answer (score 1):

The forward force is not responsible for *moving* it forward. The difference between thrust and drag is responsible for *accelerating* it forward - increasing its speed. When it gets up to its final speed, the thrust and drag cancel, so acceleration is zero - it no longer increases its speed.

Its speed doesn't decrease either, unless (thrust - drag) goes negative due to decreasing thrust, meaning negative acceleration. "Putting on the brakes."